# Nesting Foreach Loops in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a class that has this type of structure:

```
Class League
    Array Teams

Class Teams
    Array Players

Class Players
    String name
```

However, if I want to get a list of all players in the league, this doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach ($league->teams->players as $player) {
    echo $player->name;
}
```

What am I missing? Do you have to use two foreach loops?

Comment: foreach ($league->teams as $t => $p{
 echo $p->name;
}

I think if you loop it as a key => value pair, you'll get rid of one layer.

Comment: unless you give us what $league is initialized with, it is hard to give a definitive answer. Most likely what you need is Adrian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
<?php

//Create your players
$player1 = new stdClass;
$player2 = new stdClass;
$player3 = new stdClass;

$player1->name = 'Mike';
$player2->name = 'Luke';
$player3->name = 'Smith';

//Create your teams
$team1 = new stdClass;
$team2 = new stdClass;

//Adding the players to their teams
$team1->Players = array($player1, $player2);
$team2->Players = array($player3);

//Create the league
$league = new stdClass;

//Adding the teams to the league
$league->Teams = array($team1, $team2);

//For each element in the Teams array get the team in $team
foreach ($league->Teams as $teams) {
//For each element in the Players array get the player in $player
  foreach($teams->Players as $player) {
//Print the name
    echo $player->name . "<br>\n";
  }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Mike
Luke
Smith
```

Comment: This one is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

So those are three separate classes, not a single class. You have shown nothing about how you relate those classes together and how you actually create the data structure.  I don't see how you think you will be able to magically be able to list all players with a call such as `$league->teams->players` without having specific methods within each of the class to deal with aggregation from data stored in nested objects.

Without defining these relationships in your classes, you would need to do nested loops like this:

```
foreach ($league->Teams as $team) {
    foreach($team->Players as $player) {
        echo $player->name;
    }
}
```

If you want methods to, for example list all players at the league level, you would need to define a methods to do this.  Perhaps something like:

In team class:

```
public function function get_all_players() {
    $return = array();
    if(count($this->Players) > 0) {
        $return = $this->Players;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

In league class:

```
public function get_all_players() {
    $return = array();
    if(count($this->Teams) > 0) {
        foreach($this->Teams as $team) {
            $return = array_merge($return, $team->get_all_players());
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Usage would be:

```
foreach($league->get_all_players() as $player) {
    echo $player->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need two nested `foreach`

```
foreach ($league->teams as $team;){
  foreach ($team->players as $player){
    $list[] = $player->name;

   }
}
```